# How can I open Preference screen by long press from a key of sample keyboard?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, android-preferences, preferencescreen

I am a beginner about java and android. I am learning about Sample softkeyboard in Android studio. I want to know how I can open Preference Screen by long press on a key (like Globe key) of sample keyboard instead of going to Setting menu of my phone. Thank you. 
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Any luck with long-pressing key on custom android keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Thats the way you can open the preference screen with a button click

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.btnPrefs:
      Intent intent = new Intent(PreferenceActivity.this,
      PrefsActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      break;
```

The long click is something like following

```
btn.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```